# How to apply pretty print to JSX in codepen?

Tags: reactjs, pretty-print, codepen

Is there a hotkey (or really any feature) to apply pretty print to my code in CodePen?

Specifically for the JSX:

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <Card title="Card1" />
    </div>
  <div class="row">
   <Card title="Card2"/>
    </div>
  <div class="row">
   <Card title="Card3"/>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you  are using visual studio code then there is option format document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***Tidy JS*** feature of CodePen:

**Before:**

[image: Before pretty formatting]

**After:**
[image: After pretty formatting]